# Limit Convergence

Tags: calculus

Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ converge to $e$ pretty quickly or pretty slowly?

How can this be shown by using $f(x)=e-(1+x)^{1/x}$ with $x$ replacing $\frac{1}{n}$ and the Taylor Theorem with Remainder?

Comment: I think pretty slow, compared for example with $$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$$

Comment: Show that the Taylor series of $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/x}$ is $e - ex/2 + 11ex^2/2 + \dots$. In fact, just write down the linear approximation plus the error term. Now subtract. You should find that $e - (1+1/n)^n \sim \frac{e}{2n}$, which is slow indeed.

Comment: @HansEngler: I got that the Taylor series is $e-\frac{ex}{2}+\frac{11ex^2}{24}-\frac{7ex^3}{16}+...$. Using your linear approximation idea I did find that it is approximately $\frac{e}{2n}$, but why does that mean it is slow?

Comment: @Michelle - To get an additional digit of $e$, you would have to increase $n$ by a factor of 10. For example if $n = 13$, the error is about 0.1 in magnitude. To get an error of 0.01, you need to take $n = 130$. Forget about $n = 14, 15, \dots, 129$, these values are not useful. To get an error of 0.001, you need $n \approx 1300$. And so on. That is slow.

Comment: @HansEngler: That makes sense, thanks for explaining.